# asp.net refresh part of page whit jquery when application state change

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I use application property to count number of online users:

```
Application["OnlineUsers"] = (int)Application["OnlineUsers"] + 1;
```

and then bind Application property value to HTML tag

```
<div id="OnlineUser" >
    <span>Number of Online Users is <%=Application["OnlineUsers"].ToString() %></span> 
</div>
```

When for example `user1` visit page, `DIV` tag show `Number of Online Users is 1`, and `user2` visit page, DIV tag show `Number of Online Users is 2`, but `user1` still `Number of Online Users is 1`

How do I refresh `user1` page when `user2` change application property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you can try with Ajax (Timer + Updatepanel)

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="ScriptManager1">
      </asp:ScriptManager>

      <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Timer runat="server" id="Timer1" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
          <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Page not refreshed yet." id="Label1">
          </asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>


<div id="test" runat="server" >
</div>


    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test.Text = "Application["OnlineUsers"].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: You can use your div by replacing the label, but you use ajax to get the value with timer

Comment: this code not work for me ..i get Number of online user in golbale.ascx with Session_End and Session_start event